# Problem with double screen when turn on the PC

Tags: grub2, screen, hdmi, vga

when I turn on the pc the GRUB appear in my VGA screen and I want that GRUB appear in my HDMI screen, any solution?

Answer (score 0):

When `grub` is running, no device drivers have been loaded yet, so it's basically running in BIOS mode, so this depends entirely on your BIOS.

That being said, I've made it work on a PC with a broken laptop screen by turning off the power management features of the monitor but that was: guess it: *using a VGA cable instead of the HDMI cable*, so I think you're out of luck unless your primary monitor can be used with something else then VGA and the HDMI screen can be connected with the VGA cable...

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask

Comment: @A.B. : I was under the impressing that grub itself loaded initrd, so when in grub-mode, only the EFI device drivers are loaded when running in UEFI mode and nothing yet when running in BIOS mode...  Chat???  **;-)**